Circular setup of Stern–Gerlach experiment and repeated measurements
Let us start with the standard Stern–Gerlach experiment which separates an electron beam either up or down as they pass through and are deflected by an inhomogeneous magnetic field. We can find the magnitude of the deflection angle the electron beam makes by measurement, i.e. the electron hits a screen either upwards or downwards at some angle with respect to the horizontal.

Knowing this angle, we remove the measurement screen from before and we can position another set of identical magnets such that we measure the electron spin again but slightly rotated as shown in my rough sketch above.
I know that repeated measurements of the electron spin will result in the same measurement result that you got prior, therefore the electron beam that went up, should continue to to deflect upwards at the same angle because we use an identical set of magnets. If we continue this process, can we obtain a circular path? If so, then does this mean we can make a magnetic trap using inhomogeneous permanent magnets that require no electricity?
Note: In my rough sketch, I omitted the beam that goes downwards because we could very well make another set of magnets that make a circle but downwards.

Note the Stern-Gerlach experiment never deflected a beam of electrons. They were silver atoms. They rely on the particles to have a magnetic moment, but no net charge. Otherwise the $v\times B$ force would dominate by far.

Yes, I should have said neutral silver atoms or a beam of these atoms, not a beam of electrons.

It seems you would need the standard setup: [Stern-Gerlach], and then make the particles aligned with the field bend in the right way, which would require bent magnets like this:

where only one polarization gets through, of course (the one aligned with the field). Some thoughts:

I do not see how you could (as you suggest) use some setup of the magnets to preserve the other beam as well. If they both start in the same direction it won't work, but also not
if the other polarization runs in the other direction (unlike with charged particles, where opposite charges can give opposite beams with the same field magnets).
You can't do it with electrons, or other charged particles, they would get a (much bigger) force sideways than the gradient force inward that we want to use here. So here we need uncharged particles, but with a magnetic dipole (as the silver atoms in the original experiment).
The magnets have to be much stronger than when we would use charged particles, but the energy loss by synchrotron radiation would be much less than with charged particles.
You will somehow need to keep the beam focused, and also to keep the magnetic dipole pointing inwards (because that is the direction aligned with the field, so it cannot stay in a fixed direction!)
Keeping the dipole aligned with the field is probably easier than to keep it anti-aligned, so the setup in the picture above would be preferable to the one below: (where the anti-aligned particles follow the right beam path)



Actually, interestingly, the bottom picture would work and the upper picture wouldn't be stable (see the last paragraph of my answer). Otherwise you make lots of good points

O dear... did I make a minus sign error? :-)  OK, I did say "probably" so that was covered!

Honestly I didn't understand your statement "keeping the dipole aligned with the field is probably easier." My argument is more along the lines that there are high field seeking states and low field seeking states. And there can be a magnetic field magnitude minimum in free space but there cannot be a maximum in free space (its a theorem). So it is only possible to trap the low field seeking states - in this setup or any setup like it.

@AXensen I see, my "keeping the dipole aligned"  means that it has to remain pointing to the N-pole, or S-pole, but that means rotating 360 degrees during one circular orbit (unlike an electric charge, which can just remain the same charge all around). To actually make the dipole rotate like this, we constantly need a little bit of torque, so it has to be slightly misaligned all the time, but that kind of tweaking is of course not unusual. Whether this mechanism would give extra instability problems I don't know. I just guessed that (for that purpose) the upper drawing would work better.

For your point 1, I was imaging that the set of magnets have large gaps between them. So I was thinking that between the first and second set of magnets, there might have been a large enough gap to accommodate the two neutral silver atoms beam paths. But regardless, I presume there can be a path that makes a full circle? I also should have wrote neutral silver atoms not an electron beam.

What you have described is essentially a magnetic minimum trap, sometimes also called an Ioffe-Pritchard trap.
Yes, you can arrange permanent magnets such that it traps neutral particles with a magnetic moment. As I described in a comment, the Stern-Gerlach experiment never deflected electrons; they were silver atoms. They had two Zeeman sublevels, one which was attracted to high magnetic field, and one which was attracted to low magnetic field. This is used to trap neutrons
(Measuring the neutron lifetime using magnetically trapped neutrons) and antihydrogen (Observation of the effect of gravity on the motion of antimatter - this is the group I used to work for; there are many more papers using this principle, but this is the most recent).
The operating principle is a bit simpler than what you describe though. You set up an arrangement of current-carrying wires that makes it so that the magnitude of the magnetic field has a minimum in the center of your trap. Then any atom in a Zeeman sublevel which increases in energy with $|\mathbf{B}|$ will be attracted to the center of the trap. One such example is shown below, where antihydrogen atoms are confined to a cylindrical region. The "octupole" magnet makes it so the magnetic field increases as you move outward radially, and the "mirror coils" make it so the magnetic field increases as you move outward along the axis of the trap. Note that there is also a solenoid which makes a constant magnetic field.

from the paper The ALPHA antihydrogen trapping apparatus.
Note that in order for such a trap to work, the magnetic field needs to be strong enough to satisfy the "adiabatic condition." That condition is that the the Larmor frequency (the frequency that the spin goes around the magnetic field) is much faster than changes in direction of the magnetic field. This is similar to how, in your setup, you need to measure the spin frequently enough that it is not allowed to change.
To my knowledge, this has never been done with permanent magnets, although I have heard some discussion among colleagues proposing the idea. At ALPHA, the magnetic field varies from $1\,\mathrm{T}$ to $2\,\mathrm{T}$, yielding a trap depth of roughly $0.5$ Kelvin. In principle, similar magnetic field strengths can be achieved with Neodymium magnets. However some magnetic minimum traps use superconductors anyways, which in principle can make magnetic fields with no energy input just like permanent magnets (except to get them started in the beginning).
One interesting wrinkle is that because of Earnshaw's theorem, it is not possible to make a maximum in the magnetic field magnitude in free space. Therefore the same principle cannot be used to trap "low field seeking" Zeeman sublevels. What does this mean for your setup/the fixed version described in Jos' answer? Well if you the low field seeking version in Jos' lower picture it could work. If you make the high field seeking version in the upper picture, it would always be unstable. The particles would be deflected in/out of the screen assuming they weren't perfectly centered to begin with. That's not to say the nominal Stern-Gerlach experiment does actually have a magnetic minimum, just that it's possible to set it up to have a magnetic minimum.

While it's theoretically interesting to consider using spin-dependent magnetic deflection to guide electrons in a circular path, in practice, this would not result in circular motion as understood in classical terms. Instead, electrons can be made to move in circular paths through the application of a uniform magnetic field perpendicular to their velocity, which is a separate phenomenon from the quantum mechanical spin-based deflection observed in experiments like Stern-Gerlach.For trapping electrons, using inhomogeneous magnetic fields from permanent magnets could be explored, but achieving the necessary field configuration and stability likely requires the adjustable nature of electromagnets. Thus, while permanent magnets can play a role, they might not suffice for a complete, practical magnetic trapping solution without the aid of electrically controlled fields.
